# Outer derivative of a test function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I am a bit confused with the outer derivative in general and especially, how to calculate it. 
In my case I have a open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, additionally, there exists a test function $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, where $C_0^\infty(\Omega) = \{ f \in C^\infty(\Omega): \operatorname{supp}(f) := \overline{\{x: f(x) \neq 0 \}} \text{ is compact in } \Omega \} $. 
My question is now, what is the outer derivative of this test function on $\partial \Omega$?
- My guess would be that it is zero since $\varphi$ needs to be zero at the boundary of $\Omega$ or I am totally wrong?

Maybe it is so simple but I am getting confused every time with the expression outer derivative. So if someone has a good explanation, please share it with me :). In general, I know that the outer derivative is the derivative along the outer normal of the set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess would be that it is zero since $\varphi$ needs to be zero at the boundary of $\Omega$ or I am totally wrong?

You're only a little tiny bit wrong. Vanishing on the boundary is not enough to conclude that the outer derivative is zero. For example, $\varphi(x) = x^2-1$ is zero on the boundary of $[-1,1]$, but the outer derivative is non-zero.

But the actual explanation is easy anyway. If the support $\overline{\{x: \varphi(x) \neq 0 \}}$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$ (which itself is open), it means that there is a positive distance (say, $\delta > 0$) from $\operatorname{supp} \varphi$ to $\partial \Omega$. Hence, for a given point $x \in \partial \Omega$, $\varphi$ is zero not only at $x$, but on the whole ball $B_\delta(x)$ around $x$. In consequence, all its derivatives are zero in this region (and the outer derivative at $x$ in particular).

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this argument today but was not sure. Thanks a lot!